# How to filter edges by attributes in Gephi?

Tags: graph, visualization, graph-visualization, gephi

I have some edges with their corresponding labels, and I want to filter in only records with label 1, but it just doesn't work as shown below.

[image]

The function works to filter in nodes but doesn't work for edges. I thought it would be due to that there were too many edges, then I tried .gexf files with only hundreds of edges, but the problem remains. I also tried to create a new column in the app or create the column using Python in the .gexf file, but both failed. Sometimes an error arises: an error occurred while fetching data.

I wonder how to filter in only matched edges on Gephi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It seems that you must have an entry for every edge in the `Label` column.**

What you can do in your situation:

1. Sort the edges according to `Label` by clicking on the column name (might click twice).
2. Select edges that don't have a label yet.
3. Right-click: `Edit all edges`.
4. Give a default `Label` in the edit menu.

If you don't already have labels and want to manually assign them in the Data Table, you can also use `Fill column with a value` and give a default value to every edge.

This is probably a bug since we get a NullPointerException sometimes, probably because filtering doesn't expect null values in the label column (at least judging after a quick glance at the stack trace). You might file this to their GitHub Issue Page [over here](https://github.com/gephi/gephi/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+filtering).

Answer (score 0):

In addition:

A useful [tutorial](https://seinecle.github.io/gephi-tutorials/generated-html/using-filters-en.html) notes: "However, looking at the "catalogue" of filters, we see no filter on Label. The reason is that Label is an internal property of nodes, inaccessible to filters. So we must first copy the Labels of the nodes in a new attribute, which we will be able to apply a filter on." Whilst the tutorial refers to nodes the same idea works for edges: create a new edge column named whatever you choose and copy your edge labels into it. You can filter using this new column. NB: I can find the filter under Attributes: Equal but not Attributes: Partition, but it may help you. NNB: If you can't see the filter after creating the new column, you may have to hit Reset at the top of the Filters panel.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).